# Hibernate could not extract resultset exception - many to many relation

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two tables, boy and girl. Let's say that boy and girl tables have a many to many relation. In my boy entity I have defined the following Set:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
public Set<Girl> getGirls() {
     return girls;
}
```

Now the in the Girl entity I have defined the following Set:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "boy_girl", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "girl_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "boy_id")})
public Set<Boy> getBoys() {
    return boys;
}
```

I'm trying to retreive the girls by boys. In other words, I want a list of girls for a specific boyId. Here is the hql i'm using and i get the error mentioned previously:

```
String query = "FROM Girl g inner join Boy b where b.boyId = :boyId";

Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
Set<Girl> girlSet = new HashSet<Girl>();
girlSet = (Set<Interaction>) session.createQuery(query).setParameter("boyId", boyId).getResultList();
```

Here is the exact error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

Any ideas? Thanks!!

Comment: Does the column "girl_id" you reference on join exist?

Comment: This `Set<Girl> girlSet = new HashSet<Interaction>();` compiles ?

Comment: You could enable `show sql` property in Hibernate to see generated query and observe what it gets from the database. If Hibernate doesn't actually come to the query generation stage - this fact would also be a good piece of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add mappedBy if your planning to have this relationship as bi-directional here:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "boys")
public Set<Girl> getGirls() {
     return girls;
}
```

I would also suggest not marking the @ManyToMany as eager.. but its your call.

Finally change the query to:

```
String query = "FROM Girl g inner join g.boys b where b.boyId = :boyId";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why would be a bad idea to mark the many to many as eager?

Comment: There may be a lot of unnecessary joins if you do not really need that data for some queries (especially if that entities has some some eager fetching of its own set). But again maybe you always will need that info.. that why i said its your call

Comment: I would like to point out, for the sake of completeness, that with Maciej's query you get as a return an Object[] containing both a Boy and a Girl object. To get just the girls the query should be edited to: SELECT g FROM Girl g inner join g.boys b where b.boyId = :boyId

Comment: @ManyToMany default type is already LAZY. No need to override.